# Android Studio выдает ошибку при создании ключа подписи приложения

Tags: java, android, android-studio, pkcs#12, keytool

[image: Android Studio KeyStores]

"Different store and key passwords not supported for PKCS12 KeyStores. Ignoring user-specified -keypass value."

Что значит эта ошибка и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это [известная проблема Android Studio 4.2](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#4.2-known-issues). Проблема связана с тем, что Android Studio 4.2 теперь запускается на JRE 11, в которой по-другому работает `keytool`.

В самой [документации Андроид](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key) рекомендуют использовать разные пароли для ключа и для keystore, но в данный момент это приводит к ошибке.

Временное решение: при создании ключа указать одинаковые пароли как для ключа, так и для keystore.

Далее, если хотите иметь разные пароли, то вы можете скачать JRE 8, и использовать `keytool`, чтобы обновить пароль:

```sh
$ keytool -keypasswd -keystore PATH_TO_KEY_STORE -alias ALIAS -storepass STORE_PASSWORD -keypass OLD_KEY_PASSWORD -new NEW_KEY_PASSWORD
```

https://stackoverflow.com/q/66621669